# Tooltip disappears after disabling and re-enabling BootstrapVue table column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tooltip, bootstrap-vue

I have a BootstrapVue table which looks like this;

[image]

When you hover your mouse on the `First Name` column, the tooltip `Tooltip for First name` will appear. The checkboxes at the top will cause the corresponding table columns to appear/disappear.

Here's the description of the bug I encounter.

I uncheck `First Name` checkbox. Column `First Name` disappears. Now, I recheck the `First Name` checkbox. Column `First Name` reappears again. This is fine. However, the tooltip no longer works when I hover my mouse on the `First Name` column.

Here's the complete code in a single HTML file.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
<b-checkbox
    :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && field.visible"
    v-for="field in showFields" 
    :key="field.key" 
    v-model="field.visible" 
    inline
  >
    {{ field.label }}
  </b-checkbox>  
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="visibleFields" bordered>  
  </b-table>
  <b-tooltip target="HeaderFirst" triggers="hover" container="HeaderFirst">
    Tooltip for First name<br>
  </b-tooltip>      
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    visibleFields() {
      return this.fields.filter(field => field.visible)
    },
    showFields() {
      return this.fields.filter(field => field.key.includes('first') || field.key.includes('last'))
    }
  },
  data: dataInit,  
})

function dataInit() {  
    
    let init_data = {};
    
    init_data.fields = [
        { key: 'id', label: 'ID', visible: true },
        { key: 'first', label: 'First Name', visible: true, 
          thAttr: {
                id: "HeaderFirst"
              }, 
        },
        { key: 'last', label: 'Last Name', visible: true },
        { key: 'age', label: 'Age', visible: true },
      ];
    init_data.items = [
        { id: 1, first: 'Mike', last: 'Kristensen', age: 16 },
        { id: 2, first: 'Peter', last: 'Madsen', age: 52 },
        { id: 3, first: 'Mads', last: 'Mikkelsen', age: 76 },
        { id: 4, first: 'Mikkel', last: 'Hansen', age: 34 },
      ];
    
    return init_data;
  }
</script>
```

I am using vue v2.6, BootstrapVue.

Comment: Maybe you just have to re-init the tooltips after showing the column?

Comment: @cloned, how do I do that? tooltip is declared in the template. It's not a javascript function that I can call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<b-tooltip>`'s target must exist in the DOM upon mounting. It does not dynamically attach a new tooltip to newly created elements in the DOM.

The first run  of your code shows a tooltip because `<b-table>` initially contains the `#HeaderFirst` element. When you uncheck the *First Name* box, the existing elements in `<b-table>` are replaced with new elements via the computed property. The elements removed from the DOM include the one that `<b-tooltip>` initially attached a tooltip to, and no new tooltip is generated after `<b-table>` was updated.

#### Solution

One solution is to render `<b-tooltip>` only when the target element is visible:

1. Create a computed prop that determines whether the `#HeaderFirst` field is visible.
2. Conditionally render `<b-tooltip>` based on that computed prop.

```js
new Vue({
  computed: {   1️⃣
    firstNameHeaderVisible() {
      return this.fields.find(field => field.thAttr?.id === 'HeaderFirst')?.visible
    }
  },
  ⋮
})
```

```html
                                               2️⃣
<b-tooltip target="HeaderFirst" v-if="firstNameHeaderVisible">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XWVdwdw?editors=1000)

Answer (score -1):

On disabled elements event `hover` is not working. You need to wrap element by other e.g. `div` where you set up tooltip and then it should work well